# How to add header to a Dataframe (created from excel with ".parse") without overwriting the first Row in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to read multiple Excel-Files from multiple sheets and files. The biggest issue is just to add an header (because the original excel-Files don't have one) to a generated dataframe of a sheet, because all used methods still overwriting the values in line/row 1 (A1, B1 ...).

Code at the moment:

```
# before the path was declared 
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

# there is additional code above which reads all the files in a folder, selecting the relevant ones and open them
sheetHeader = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]

# rotation through all excel-sheets starts 
for sheetNames in xl.sheet_names:
     df_sheetExtraction = xl.parse(sheet_names = sheetNames, 
                                   header = 0, 
                                   names = sheetHeader)

     #example for asking at the specific cell value
     if df_sheetExtraction["B"][1] == searchedValue:
           pass
```

The problem as an example (in list-form) ...

Excel: `[[11, 12, 13, 14 ...],[21, 22, 23, 24 ...], [31, 32, 33, 34 ...] ...]`

Dataframe: `[[A, B, C, D ...], [21, 22, 23, 24 ...], [31, 32, 33, 34 ...] ...]`

instead of `[[A, B, C, D ...], [11, 12, 13, 14 ...] ...]`

I tried it without the `xl.parse(..., names = ...)` and add the columns afterwards `df_sheetExtraction.columns = sheetHeader`  with the same result. Different usages in `xl.parse(..., header = ...)` won't affect the targeted result.

Is there a way to avoid combining the dataframe with a separate "header-dataframe"?

Thx for your help

Comment: Case closed ...
The following combination `(sheet_name=sheetNames, header=None, names=sheetHeader)` works like the answer below.
Resumee: The header is on "none" by default. To use a separate header like above, you have to set it explicit to "none".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `header` parameter says (emphasis mine):

> header : int, list of int, default 0
> Row (0-indexed) to use for the column labels of the parsed
> DataFrame. If a list of integers is passed those row positions will
> be combined into a `MultiIndex`. **Use None if there is no header.**

If you are looking to add your own list as the column names without replacing any of the data in the spreadsheet, you can set `header=None` and then the names, such as

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(xlsx_filename,
                       sheet_name=[sheet_name_1,sheet_name_2],
                       header=None,
                       names=['Column_A','Column_B'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The way you describe will work like wanted.

On the other side it's significantly slower than using the "pd.ExcelFile" and the "parse"-method (which only load the new sheet in the file). The reason is that in contrast "pd.read_excel(...)" always reopens the excel-file by switching through the sheets (at least i found that tip in other discussions). 
The function has to run through nearly 5k sheets (separated in different files), but necessary it will go that way.